# Char to time_t conversion always returns Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-esp8266, time-t

I am working on some code for my ESP8266 in Arduino. I want to send a timestamp to another ESP via UDP.

In the `setup(){` I initialize the time using

```
configTime(3 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
```

and in the `loop(){`

```
time_t timestamp = time(nullptr);
```

to get the time. I then send it to another ESP

```
Udp.write(ctime(&timestamp));
```

Where I need to make a time_t again to compare it to the actual time.

But for testing purposes, I send time as a char through terminal in UDP using `echo -n "Fri Feb 28 14:44:11 2020" >/dev/udp/192.168.43.248/4210`  from my MacBook Pro (MacOS Mojave).

The Serial Monitor shows the in- and output is the following:

```
UDP packet contents: Fri Feb 28 14:44:11 2020
Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969
```

My Code is:

```
time_t convertStringToTime_t(char timestamp []) {
  time_t result = time(NULL);
  const char *timestampString = timestamp;
  int weekDay, month, dd, hh, mm, ss, yyyy = 0;
  struct tm timestampFromString = {0};

  //input     Fri Feb 28 16:40:11 2020
  //output    Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969 TODO always same output?!

  sscanf(timestampString, "%s %s %d %d:%d:%d %d", &weekDay, &month, &dd, &hh, &mm, &ss, &yyyy);

  timestampFromString.tm_year = yyyy - 1900; //years since 1900
  timestampFromString.tm_mon = month - 1;
  timestampFromString.tm_wday = weekDay;
  timestampFromString.tm_mday = dd;
  timestampFromString.tm_hour = hh;
  timestampFromString.tm_min = mm;
  timestampFromString.tm_sec = ss;
  timestampFromString.tm_isdst = -1;

  result = mktime(&timestampFromString);
  // mktime   Convert tm structure to time_t
  return result;
}
```

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469262/time-function-in-c-always-displays-wed-dec-31-235959-1969) but it doesn't help me at all :/
I also tried using `sscanf` but no difference. I think I do something wrong in `scanf`?

**solved:**
Thanks to @thomachan I realized I tried to put the Month + Day chars into int's (I could solve that by converting the chars to ints).

But I listened to @Maxim Egorushkin and used the simpler approach using the time_t value:

```
char *buffer;
time_t i = strtoul(incomingPacket, &buffer, 10);
```

Comment: You can't `scanf` a string (`%s`) into an `int`.

Comment: You meant `sscanf` instead of plain `scanf`, right?

Comment: But that's what they do [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: I tried sscanf first, but made no difference

Comment: @binarykitten the page you link has a format string as the first argument of `scanf` in all cases. (Also, that site is bad)

Comment: No, they pass the address of a `char[]`, instead.

Comment: another problem is that you use `%s` format specifier while passing the address of an `int`

Comment: How you can put string in an int using int pointer, it will go out of range

Comment: But how to parse the time-char to an time_t then?

Comment: You might want to check If you have [strptime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) extension.

Comment: Show us a [mcve]  might help.

Comment: Just send the value of `time_t` - the number of seconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: that date looks a lot like `(time_t)-1`, which [is an error signal](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html), not a real `time_t` value.

Comment: tm_mon  expects a number between 0-11 and tm_wday a number between 0-6. you need to cnvert after doing an sscanf

Comment: If you had checked the return value of sscanf it would have told you which argument was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require human-readable time, you can send the value of `time_t` - the number of seconds since Unix epoch.

```
date +%s > /dev/udp/192.168.43.248/4210
```

The receiver can parse it from string to `time_t` with [`std::strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul).

Comment: how do i do that? just send the raw "time_t" object? 
`Udp.write(timestamp);`?

Comment: @binarykitten Since you send and receive text you need to convert `time_t` to a string with `std::snprintf` or `std::to_string`. `date +%s` outputs a string, try it.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly! much easier and shorter! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the choice, I suggest you pass [a ISO-8601 timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead. That looks like

```
2020-03-03T10:28:59
```

and is trivially parsed with `sscanf` (which gives you components) or `strptime` (which fills in a `struct tm`). If your platform does not provide a `strptime` implementation, you can use one from BSD.